# Loop a macro through every worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

Don't know why I cannot loop this code through all sheets. What I'd like is, once a country it's been written in the input box, to loop through every sheet executing the macro which deletes all rows not containing the chosen country. No error is displayed, it just runs the macro in the active sheet and then stops.

```
Sub Cleaner()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim savedel As Boolean
Dim cellcounter As Integer
Dim country As String

country = InputBox("Enter Country to Save")
If country = "" Then Exit Sub

cellcounter = 1

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
  If wb.Name <> "PERSONAL.xlsb" Then
    For Each sht In wb.Worksheets

   Do Until cellcounter > Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

    'Ignore deletion of any spacer rows
    If IsEmpty(Range("D" & cellcounter)) = True And IsEmpty(Range("E" & cellcounter)) = True Then
        savedel = 1

        'Ignore heading rows
        ElseIf Len(Range("F" & cellcounter)) > 0 And IsNumeric(Left(Range("F" & cellcounter), 1)) = False Then
            savedel = 1

        'Ignore deletion of the country sought
        ElseIf Range("B" & cellcounter).Value = country Then
            savedel = 1

        'Flag non-country for deletion
        ElseIf Range("B" & cellcounter).Value <> country And IsEmpty(Range("B" & cellcounter).Value) = False Then
            savedel = 0
    End If

    'If flagged, delete row
    If savedel = 0 Then
        Rows(cellcounter).Delete
        cellcounter = cellcounter - 1
    End If

      cellcounter = cellcounter + 1

   Loop

Next sht
End If
Next wb

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to move you `cellcounter` initialization.

In your loop `Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row` is always refering to the same selection, even moving from sheet to sheet. You probably also have to use `sht.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row` instead.

You also have to replace all your `Range` by something relative to your current sheet/selection `sht.Range`.

```
...
If country = "" Then Exit Sub

' Move cellcounter initialization from here...
'cellcounter = 1

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
    If wb.Name <> "PERSONAL.xlsb" Then
        For Each sht In wb.Worksheets

            ' To here:
            cellcounter = 1

            Do Until cellcounter > sht.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

            'Ignore deletion of any spacer rows
            If IsEmpty(sht.Range("D" & cellcounter)) = True _
            And IsEmpty(sht.Range("E" & cellcounter)) = True Then
                savedel = 1

            'Ignore heading rows
            ElseIf Len(sht.Range("F" & cellcounter)) > 0 And _
            IsNumeric(Left(sht.Range("F" & cellcounter), 1)) = False Then
                savedel = 1

            'Ignore deletion of the country sought
            ElseIf sht.Range("B" & cellcounter).Value = country Then
                savedel = 1

            'Flag non-country for deletion
            ElseIf sht.Range("B" & cellcounter).Value <> country _
            And IsEmpty(sht.Range("B" & cellcounter).Value) = False Then
                savedel = 0

            End If
...
```

Comment: Nope, still doing nothing for the not active sheets :(

Comment: As I said in my answer, you have to use `sht.Range` instead of `Range`. Updated to show you.

Comment: It seems now is working, thanks ;) Only thing is that Excel freezes so I don't know if the execution will finish or will crash.